# Pass a variable to a path/command in python

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, subprocess

I am new to Python. I want to execute a script which has parameters in python. Please have a look at below example on what I finally want to achieve.

I have a script with parameters:

```
PATH="ABCXYZ"
username = "admin"
password = "pass"
query = "select * from user;"
OUTPUT = /usr/local/<PATH>/dbscript -u username -p password -q query
```

How can I pass a `PATH` variable in "/usr/local/<**PATH**>/dbscript" here ?

I tried with `os.system` & `subprocess`, But We cannot use variable in between.
I want that `OUTPUT` variable data which will print `yes` or `no` or `some number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below must work.

```
import subprocess as sp
PATH="ABCXYZ"
username = "admin"
password = "pass"
query = "select * from user;"
command = "/usr/local/%s/dbscript -u %s -p %s -q %s" % (PATH, username, password, query)
#Next line print '/usr/local/ABCXYZ/dbscript -u admin -p pass -q select * from user;' for me.
print command # 
sp.Popen(command.split(), shell=True)
```

Furthermore you should play with `shell` parameter and useful read [it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

Comment: @MichaelKazarian I gave command like "Traceback (most recent call last):File "file.py" , line 20, in <module>
    command = "/usr/local/%s/dbscript -u %s -p %s -q %s" % (PATH, username, pass, query) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Comment: @San In `command = ...` I have found bug and checked it. Now all work for me.